# hasChanged useless if "only useful during the course of a 'change' event"?

Tags: backbone.js

Seems confusing to have a `hasChanged()` method you can call on a model, but which is only "useful" during a `change` event.  Doesn't the fact that a `change` event has been fired mean the model has changed?

Is the only usage of `hasChanged()` to detect if a model has changed if user-written code is manually triggering the model's `change` event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is the only usage of `hasChanged()` to detect if a model has changed if user-written code is manually triggering the model's `change` event?

This is certainly one strong use-case for the `.hasChanged` method, but another - potentially far more powerful - is checking for a single property on a generic `change` event.

From [the documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-hasChanged):

> If an **attribute** is passed, returns `true` if that specific attribute has changed.

This means a single `change` binding can decide what to do based on whether individual properties have changed. It's likely this is the more useful of the two method signatures.